# Magic protection protect against FUS RO DAH?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does either Magic Resistance or Magic Absorption protect against the Stagger and Ragdoll effect of Unrelenting Force?

Magic Resistance refers to the effect from the enchantment "Resist Magic", and from "Magic Resistance" from the alteration Tree. If it does affect stagger/ragdoll, how does it affect it?

Magic Absorption refers to the effect of the Atronach Stone and Atronach perk from the alteration Tree.

Comment: Wards do, while casting them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Magic Resistance and Magic Absorption only apply to the actual damage that is dealt by a magical spell or shout. Thus while it will mitigate the damage that Shouts will deal to you, as the stagger is an effect that is separate from the damage, it will not.

Source: Turned on console commands, got 100% Magic Resistance and 100% Magic Absorption chance with crazy enchantments and still got staggered.

However you can use wards to block it